# Table Not Obeying Container Heights

Tags: html, css, height, containers, percentage

I'm working on a HTML page which I intend to use with PHP later however I have encountered some issues with the height scaling.

My tables and also the elements within the tables are not abiding by the height limits I have set within  a container.

I do not want it to extend beyond the page as that would require a scroll bar. Anybody have any suggestions? (Other feedback is welcome)

Code HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="summonerTable.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navBar.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="summonerContainer">
    <div class="navbar">
    </div>
    <div id="gameDetails">
    </div>
    <table border="1" id="summonerTeams">
    <tr height="100%">
<!-- Begin Definitions !-->
        <td>

            <table width="100%" id="summonerTeamsDetails" height="100%">
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Summoner Name
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" height="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="red">
                    <tr>
<!--                        <td width="50%" background="ChampionIcon.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello">-->
                        <td width="25%" bgcolor="aqua">
                            <img src="ChampionIcon.png" id="summonerImg2" alt="Hello"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="12%">
                            <table height="100%" width="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="aqua">
                            <tr>
<!--                                <td background="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg">-->
                                <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                                    <img src="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
<!--                                <td background="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg"> -->
                                <td style="vertical-align:top;"> 
                                    <img src="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello"/>
                                </td>
                            </tor>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="75%">
                            <table height="100%" width="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="red">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <p>
                                        tryndamere
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>
                                        K/D/A: 1000/1000/1000
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Champion Games
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        KDR
                    </p>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Ranking
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Series
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Runes
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Masteries
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Ranked Wins
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Normal Wins
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Show Champion Counters
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
<!-- End Definitions !-->
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="summonerMiddleBar">
    </div>
    <table border="1" id="summonerTeams">
<!-- Summoner Details Table (2) !-->
    <tr height="100%">
<!-- Begin Definitions !-->
        <td>
            <table width="100%" id="summonerTeamsDetails" height="100%">
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Summoner Name
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="20%">
                <td>
                    <table width="100%" height="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="red">
                    <tr>
<!--                        <td width="50%" background="ChampionIcon.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello">-->
                        <td width="25%" bgcolor="aqua">
                            <img src="ChampionIcon.png" id="summonerImg2" alt="Hello"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="12%">
                            <table height="100%" width="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="aqua">
                            <tr>
<!--                                <td background="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg">-->
                                <td style="vertical-align:bottom;">
                                    <img src="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
<!--                                <td background="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg"> -->
                                <td style="vertical-align:top;"> 
                                    <img src="summonerSpell.png" id="summonerImg" alt="Hello"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width="75%">
                            <table height="100%" width="100%" id="summonerTeamDetailsInterior" bgcolor="red">
                            <tr>
                                <td bgcolor="black">
                                    <p>
                                        tryndamere
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <p>
                                        K/D/A: 1000/1000/1000
                                    </p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Champion Games
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        KDR
                    </p>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Ranking
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Series
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Runes
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Masteries
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Ranked Wins
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="5%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Normal Wins
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="10%">
                <td width="100%" bgcolor="red">
                    <p>
                        Show Champion Counters
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
<!-- End Definitions !-->
        <td>

            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p>
                AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
html, body
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    font:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    color:white;
}

.summonerContainer
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    resize:none;    
}
#summonerTeams
{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    table-layout:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    height:38%;
}
#summonerTeamsDetails
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-spacing:0;
}
#summonerTeamDetailsInterior
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;

}
#summonerMiddleBar
{
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
}
#gameDetails
{
    background-color:aqua;
    color:white;
    height:5%;
    width:100%;
}
p
{
    font-size:1.5vw;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
}
body
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#summonerImg
{
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    /*display:block;*/
}
#summonerImg2
{
    max-width:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    /*display:block;*/
}
table
{
}
```

Other CSS Code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.navbar
{
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    height:10%;
    width:100%;
}
.footer
{
    background-color:#000;
    color:white;
    height:4%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that there comes a point at which the height of 5% for the table cell is too small for the text that is contained inside so, instead of disappearing it ignores the height of the container.

To workaround this you would have to use media queries to rearrange the table - though i recommend not using a table as it will make this bit easier - so that the height is of a size that wont create scroll bars.

See here for a tutorial on media queries: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fA1NW-T1QXc

Comment: I've tried using seperate DIVS to create the different sections however that did not work well.. Do you have any pointers to where I should start with the media queries in terms of setting the CSS?

Comment: @JasonLy basically i would recommend using a css table library which does all that I have said above for you. Another thing is why do u want to have no scrolling

Comment: Okay I understand. As to why I do not want scrolling capabilities, it is because the website is designed to give brief information without having to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following lines should be corrected:

> html, body {
>   color: white; }

Setting the text color to white is a bad idea as both the text and background would have the same color, making it impossible to read some text (like the AAAAAAAAAA) and also difficult for you to decipher errors easily.

To improve on markup, it is always recommended you seperate html and css code into files of their own. That also makes the code very easy to understand. In addition, you can always view all markup errors on the web console: `ctrl+shif+k` on most mordern browsers.